# Decent specification for a starter machine learning system

Tags: machine-learning

I will be working on applying machine learning models on biological data. I am a bioinformatician and new to data science / machine learning. The data set (tentatively) contain data from 6k samples, but most of the data is sparse, i.e. most of the fields will be empty. The dataset size might be <50GB

I feel bit out of depth for the time being, but wanted to know if a system of the below specifications should handle any machine learning models I would like to try and implement.

CPU - Intel 12th gen i7 12700
GPU - nVidia 4060
RAM - 64GB
Storage - 2 TB nVME for data, 1 TB nVME for the boot drive

I can upgrade if the performance is not sufficient, but is this a good starting point, or can I use older generation of GPU? Should I prioritize CUDA cores vs VRAM?